Embedded Unity WebGL game not loading on Website
I have created a Unity game and exported the build with WebGL. I then placed the game files inside the public folder in my Next.js website. I then used iframes to try and display the game so users can play the game on my site. My website is hosted with cloud flare.
However, the game does not load. I have tried deleting caches and rebuilding the game from Unity, but the game still is not loading on the website. Here is a screenshot: 
Here is the error in the console: [![Console Error][2]][2]
Here is my file structure: File Structure
Thank you!
EDIT: I have updated my faulty file structure, however I am running Into another issue:
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.cardcounter21.com/Game/Build/Game.framework.js.br' because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.


"does not load" in what way does it not load? and dont say its not loading, we get that - but there will be messages or error codes.. none of which you have included.

@BugFinder I have added the error messages, sorry for not including them at the start

Did you read the errors? Get in the habit of reading errors!

Thank you! I'll try to push the files to cloud flare again I think thats why its not working.

@AndyRay I have updated all the game files, but there is a new error now: index.html:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://www.cardcounter21.com/Game/Build/Game.framework.js.br' because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
